# Which version of Apache Tomcat should I install in my linux server space?

Tags: apache, tomcat

I need to install Apache Tomcat on my linux server space in rackspace.com. I'm not sure which is the best version I need to use.
I also need support for PHP, Java, JSP, servlets and ASP. Do I need to install these separately or does apache/linux support these by default?
If I need to install them separately, which versions of PHP, Java, JSP, Servlets and ASP should I install?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The newer the better, I'd say. The latest stable Tomcat at the time of writing is 6.0.29. If you install Tomcat 5.5, you won't be able to run Servlet 2.5 (which, for example, is a requirement for JSF 2.0).

Although technically possible to run on Tomcat, it's more conventional to run PHP sites on Apache or lighttpd.

Now the ASP-part. ASP is a fairly old Microsoft technology and naturally, Microsoft wants you to use Windows to serve ASP-pages. There are workarounds though. There is the Apache::ASP-project, which adds ASP-support with Perl as language to Apache. There used to be a product by ChiliSoft (now Oracle) that allowed you to run VBScript-based ASPs on Unix but I don't think it's still in active development or even sold.

If it's ASP.NET you need, you have Novell's Mono, which includes a module to run ASP.NET pages on Apache.

Comment: Thanks sicn. If I choose to install Tomcat 6.0.29, which version of Java should I install?

Comment: In theory 1.5 is enough but unless you have a very good reason, you should use 1.6.0_21 (which, at the time of writing, is the latest).

Answer (score 3):

The latest, unless you have a genuine reason for choosing otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Note that Quercus is a Java implementation of PHP.  Apparently it can run WordPress and much more http://quercus.caucho.com/